# Angular2: Binding dropdowns values with 'n' numbers

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the best way to bind drop downs values with numbers from 1 to 100 using a loop using Angular2?

For a limited number of values I am using Ngprime dropdown, but how do I achieve this for 'n' number of values?

Template:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="tests" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar" [style]="{'width':'150px'}" editable="editable" placeholder="Select a Brand"></p-dropdown>
```

Component:

```
this.tests = [];
this.test.push({label: 'Audi', value: 'Audi'});
```

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 3):

A dropdown with options from 1 to 100 in Angular 2 would be something like this:

In component:

```
export class DropDownClass {
  constructor() {
    this.numbers = new Array(100).fill(0).map((x,i + 1)=>i); // [1,2,3,4,...,100]
  }
}
```

In template:

```
<select name="my-dropdown" [(ngModel)]="myDropdownModel">
    <option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="number">{{number}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am getting an error as 'Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target'.(method) Array<any>.fill(value: any, start?: number, end?: number): any[]...Should i specify start and end value?

Comment: @AnnMary No problem. But it worked for you? Did it solve your issue/question? Did you encounter any difficulties? Have a nice day! :D

Comment: error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'fill' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fill' of undefined

Comment: What is the reason of typeerror I am facing here,TypeError: Cannot read property 'fill' of undefined

Comment: If you don't use `new` you are not instancing/creating the Array. And therefore the array doesn't exist and the compiler throws error because you try to use `fill() ` on a non existing element.

Comment: I have updated the code with new Eventhen also I am facing same issue.

Comment: @AnnMary Coudl you please update your question with this code so I can have a look? Thanks! :D

Comment: I got it working by slight change in your code.Thanks for your valuable advice @ SrAxi

Comment: @AnnMary I'm glad I was able to help you! :D Good luck and have a nice day! :P

Answer (score 1):

```
  public quantities: Array<number> = [];
 getQuantity() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      this.quantities.push(i)
    }
  }


<mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="QTY">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let quantity of quantities" [value]="quantity">
                  {{quantity}}
            </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Code

In template:

```
<label for="percentage">Percentage</label>
  <p-dropdown formControlName="PercentageAbsence" [options]="numbers" [style]="{'width':'200px'}">
  </p-dropdown>
```

In component:

```
 import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/primeng';
  export class Test{
   numbers: SelectItem[] = [];
   constructor(){
        Array(100).fill(0).map((x, i) => {
        this.numbers.push({ label: `${i + 1}`, value: i + 1 })
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In component: (YourComponent.ts)

```
export class YourComponent {
itemQuantity = []; // instantiates the object to hold array of numbers

public ngOnInit() {
    this.itemQuantity = Array(5).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i+1); // fills array with 5 incremental entries starting from 1 (hence the "i+1"). To start at zero remove the "+1"
}
```

}

In template: (YourComponent.html)

```
<option *ngFor="let number of itemQuantity" value="{{number}}">{{number}}</option>
```

The result is a dropdown list with five entries numbered 1 to 5

"value="{{number}}" is optional, in case you want different text and value for each select item, e.g. to get **Number 1** you can use **Number {{number}}**